# 2 ODBC queries into one HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, odbc, progress-db

I'm trying to acccess data from 2 separate ODBC connections; one from a MySQL database, the other from PROGRESS and I would like to compare data from the two and output to an HTML table. Here is my code as is at the minute which doesn't work obviously. Any and all help appreciated:

```
<?php

    //select data from MySQL.
    $sql = "SELECT 
            *
            FROM quotation
            WHERE order_no IN ('$order_no')
            ORDER BY order_no, order_line ASC
            ";
    $rs = odbc_exec($mysqlconn, $sql);


    //select data from MFG-PRO.
    $sql2 = "SELECT 
            sod_nbr,
            sod_line,
            sod_qty_ord,
            sod_std_cost
            FROM sod_det
            WHERE sod_nbr IN ('$order_no')
            ORDER BY sod_nbr, sod_line ASC
            ";
    $rs2 = odbc_exec($oconn, $sql2);


    // build array
    while($row1=odbc_fetch_array($rs) && $row2=odbc_fetch_array($rs2))
    { 

        echo '<tr>
                  <td><input type="text" name="quotation[]"       value="'.$row1['idquotation'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="order_no[]"        value="'.$row1['order_no'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="order_date[]"      value="'.$row1['order_date'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="customer[]"        value="'.$row1['customer'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="order_line[]"      value="'.$row1['order_line'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="part[]"            value="'.$row1['part'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="order_qty[]"       value="'.$row1['order_qty'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="standard_cost[]"   value="'.$row1['standard_cost'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="created_by[]"      value="'.$row1['created_by'].'" readonly/></td>
              ';

        echo '
                  <td><input type="text" name="sod_line[]"       value="'.$row2['sod_line'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="sod_qty_ord[]"    value="'.$row2['sod_qty_ord'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="sod_std_cost[]"   value="'.$row2['sod_std_cost'].'" readonly/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="valid[]"          value="';

        echo ''.'" readonly/></td>';

    }
```

?>

Comment: Why is it obvious that it doesn't work?  Are you getting an error that you haven't shared?  I'm guessing that the sod_det query is the Progress db -- that table looks familiar.  All of the data from the 4gl engine lives in the PUB schema so the first problem that I see is that you need to prefix the tables with "PUB."

Comment: I agree with Tom. Can you share the errors you're getting?